# Istio (1.6.2) : RBAC Access Denied for Valid JWT Token

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, istio

I'm new to Istio. I'm implementing Authorization with JWT. I get RBAC access denied error for a valid JWT token. I've added the JWT Payload and Authorization Policy for reference. I'm using kubernetes version v1.18.3 and Istio 1.6.2. I'm running cluster on minikube.

JWT Payload:

```
{
  "iss": "https://dev-n63ipah2.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "sEbjHGBcZ16D0jk8wohIp7vPoT0MWTO0@clients",
  "aud": "http://10.97.72.213/",
  "iat": 1594125596,
  "exp": 1594211996,
  "azp": "sEbjHGBcZ16D0jk8wohIp7vPoT0MWTO0",
  "scope": "read:contact write:contact update:contact delete:contact",
  "gty": "client-credentials"
}
```

Authorization Policy:

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "AuthorizationPolicy"
metadata:
  name: dex-ms-contact-require-jwt
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dex-ms-contact
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       requestPrincipals: ["https://dev-n63ipah2.us.auth0.com/sEbjHGBcZ16D0jk8wohIp7vPoT0MWTO0@clients"]
    to:
    - operation:
       methods: ["*"]
       paths: ["*"]
    when:
    - key: request.auth.claims[iss]
      values: ["https://dev-n63ipah2.us.auth0.com/"]
```

After applying authorization policy I hit GET http://10.97.72.213/contact/1 API through Postman and I get 403 Forbidden RBAC: access denied.

Note: 10.97.72.213 is the Public Ipaddress of the Minikube cluster.

Comment: Hi, can You add the envoy logs to see why Your request got denied? You can find out how to get these logs from [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/security-issues/#ensure-proxies-enforce-policies-correctly).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Istio documentation:

```
requestPrincipals - Optional. A list of request identities (i.e. “iss/sub” claims), which matches to the “request.auth.principal” attribute.
```

In your case the `iss` is `https://dev-n63ipah2.us.auth0.com/` and the `sub` is `https://dev-n63ipah2.us.auth0.com/`, so the you probably want something like this:

```
- from:
    - source:
       requestPrincipals: ["https://dev-n63ipah2.us.auth0.com//sEbjHGBcZ16D0jk8wohIp7vPoT0MWTO0@clients"]
```

(please note the double slash - first is part of iss the second is the separator).

Comment: Did you user a base64 enconde to get the string "sEbjHGBcZ16D0jk8wohIp7vPoT0MWTO0" or it is the client id?